# Springboot Hibernate Entity Mapping

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have three tables with primary key in each table : table packetname, table customer, and table rent.

Table **PacketName**

```
public class PacketName implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idpacket;
    private String packetname;
    private String packetdesc;
    private String packetprize;
    private String packettime;
    //getter and setter etc
}
```

Table **Customer**

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long costumerid;

    private String costumername;
    private String governmentname;
    private String costumeraddress;
    private String costumeremail;
    @NotNull
    private String costumerphone;

    @NotNull
    private String customer_username;
    @NotNull
    private String customer_password;
    ...
    //getter and setter
}
```

Table **Rent**

```
@Entity
public class Rent implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long idrent;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date registerdate;
    private Date updatedate;
    private Date expdate;
    private String rentstatus;
    ....
    //getter and setter
}
```

My Question is:
How to get idpacketname, packetname from tabel packetname and idcustomer from table customer into table rent. so i know that a customer rent a packet and give the detail in table rent about expdate and rentstatus.

Sorry for my bad writing question, i'm new in this stackoverflow
thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, table RENT should represent many-to-many relationship between tables PACKETNAME and CUSTOMER. So, you should have properties of type PacketName and Customer in your Rent entity with propper annotations.

[Short example:](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-many-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/)